# What is exact sequence of operations made here?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function:

```
std::string makeMeat() { return "Pork"; }
```

And somewhere in code I use it this way:

```
std::string meat = makeMeat();
```

I want to know what is exact sequence of operations made on this line of code. Assuming two different circumstances:

1. std::string has no move constructor (just for example)
2. std::string has move constructor

I guess `makeMeat()` creates temporary object of class `std::string`.

```
std::string temp("Pork");
```

After that `std::string meat` object is created and initialized with copy constructor by data from `temp` object?

```
std::string meat(temp);
```

Finally `temp` object is destroyed?

I think it happens this way if there was no return value optimization.
What happens if it was?

Comment: This is very simple to test yourself. Instead of using a `std::string` you create your own class with the wanted constructors and functions, which print a message when they are called. Then you can see for yourself what happens.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg With things like copy elision coming into play, I'd say "try it yourself" will indeed give you *an* answer, but not one which reflects all that must happen, can happen, needs to be available etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test this using a custom structure:

```
struct S {
    S (const char *);
    S (S const&) = default;
    S (S&&) = default;
    virtual ~S();
};

S get_s () { return "S"; }

int main () {
    S s = get_s();
}
```

Without option, g++ will elide most constructors call and this code is equivalent to:

```
S s("S");
```

So only the constructor from `const char *` is called.

Now, if you tell g++ to not elide constructor (`-fno-elide-constructors`), there are three constructors/destructors call:

1. The first one create a temporary `S("S")`;
2. The second one create a temporary inside `get_s`, `S(S&&)`;
3. Then the destructor of the first temporary is called;
4. Then the move constructor is called inside `main`;
5. Then the destructor of the temporary returned by `get_s` is called;
6. Then the destructor of `s` is called.

If `S` does not have a move constructor, you can simply replace move constructors by copy constructors in the above list.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about the second step? Does it create an object which is actually "returned" to the main flow?

Comment: @vector2718 There are three places in memory where storage for a `S` object is allocated in this procedure: A) In the main function, B) In the "call stack" of `get_s`, C) In the stack of `get_s`. The object `S("S")` is first constructed in `C`, then moved in the return place `B`, then moved in its target place `A`.

Comment: I understand C) as a stack frame of get_s which stores all arguments and local variables of this function. But what do you mean by "call stack" of get_s?

Comment: @vector2718 "call stack" may be a bad term here - When you have a function that return something, you need to store the return value somewhere. Depending on the calling convention, you may store it on a register (e.g. with `__stdcall`) or somewhere in memory (in the "call stack").

Answer (score 3):

The string is directly constructed in `meat`.  No temporaries with a distinct lifetime exist.  This is known as elision.

This behaviour is mandated under C++17 and in practice happens in any reasonably modern production-quality modern compiler with no pathological build flags set in C++03 11 and 14.

In C++14 and earlier, the class must have a move or copy ctor for the above to happen, or you get a build break.  No code in said constructors will run.

Ancient or toy compilers, or compilers with pathological flags telling them not to elide, may make up to 2 temporary objects and mess around with copies.  This case isn't interesting, as pathological compiler states are equally free to implement `a+=b;` (with `a` and `b` integral types) as `for (i from 0 to b)++a;`!  You should honestly consider lack of elision as equally pathological.

Elision in C++ refers to the standard-permitted merging of object lifetime and identity.  So in some sense 3 strings (the temporary eithin the function, the return value, and the value constructed from the return value) exist, their identities are merged into one object with a unified lifetime.

Comment: Not sure but: `"Pork"` is not a prvalue of type `std::string`, so the compiler is not required to perform copy elision in C++17.

Comment: @holt but we construct a prvalue of type `std::string` to return there *from* `"Pork"`, the return that, no?  Not absolutely sure, but I would be disappointed if not true.

Comment: @Holt: The compiler is never *"required"* to perform copy-elision. It is only "allowed" to do that.

Comment: @Nawaz We are speaking about C++17 in which some copy-elision will be mandatory.

Comment: @holt and I think the C to B as well.  I should double check.  Reading [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0135r1.html) now...

Comment: Both are required to be "elided" in C++17; there is nothing requiring a temporary materialization conversion anywhere.

Comment: @Yakk @T.C. There was a "modification" on the definition of `prvalue` made especially for this, which I skipped, so with this new definition of `prvalue`, I think that in this context, `"Pork"` is a `prvalue` of type `std::string`, so both copy will effectively be elided.

Comment: @t.c. I just went and tracked down the paragraphs!  Well I remain convinced and reassured.